# Boolean comparison of null values in postgres arrays

Tags: postgresql, null

I have the following table:

```
   id    | row_2 
---------+---------------
       1 | {t,NULL}
       2 | {NULL}
```

I want to keep  the rows that are either true or NULL
 and filter out the rows in which the array contains 
a false value. I did this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_table t
WHERE
    not (false = ANY (t.row_2));
```

This doesn't work because a comparison with a null value
results in null. That is, this...

```
SELECT not false = any (ARRAY[true, true]);
SELECT not false = any (ARRAY[false, false]);
```

...outputs true and false respectively (as expected). But this...

```
SELECT not false = any (ARRAY[true, null]);
```

...outputs `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is good to use [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to correct `null` comparisons:

```
select *
from my_table
where not coalesce(false = any(row_2), false)
```

[Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=32518fa846da1017d35bfa6138f7fdf0)

Note, that per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) of `ANY/SOME(array)` (emphasis mine):

> Also, if the right-hand array contains any null elements and **no true comparison result is obtained,** the result of ANY will be null, not false